# Поиск совпадений в переменной, со значениями из массива

Tags: php, php7

Для поиска значения в переменной, использую:

```
strpos($var, 'Искомое значение')
```

Каким образом возможно искать массив значений в переменной?

Comment: цикл или регулярка чем-то не угодили?

Comment: @teran не могли бы вы помочь с циклом? Дать пример.